# Azure SQL DB - data file export (.csv) from azure sql

Tags: sql, azure, csv

I am new to Azure SQL. 
We have a client db which is in Azure SQL. We need to set up a process automation which extract query results to .CSV files and load it in our server (on premise SQL server 2008 R2).

What is the best method to generate csv files from Azure sql and make it accessible for the on premise server?

Answer (score 2):

Honestly the best in terms of professional approach is to use Azure Data Factory and installation of Integration Runtime on the on premises.

You of course can use BCP but it will be cumbersome in the long run. A lot of scripts, tables, maintenance. No logging, no metrics, no alerts... Don't do it honestly.

SSIS is another option butin my opinion it takes more effort than ADF solution.

Azure Data Factory will allow you to do this in professional way using user interface with no coding. It also can be parametrized so you just change name of table name parameter and suddenly you are exporting 20, 50 or 100 tables at ease.

Here is video example and intro into data factory if you want to see quick overview. In this overview there is also demo which imports CSV to Azure SQL, you can just change it a little bit to make Azure SQL -> CSV and CSV > SQL server or just directly Azure SQL > SQL server.

https://youtu.be/EpDkxTHAhOs

It really is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using simple [bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) from the on prem environment save the results to csv and then load the csv into the on prem server.

You can also use [SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services) to implement an automated task.

Though I would like to know why you need the intermediate csv file? you can simply just copy data between databases (cloud -> On prem) with a scheduled [SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services) package.

Answer (score 0):

If you have on-prem SQL access then a simple SSIS package is probably the quickest and easiest way to go. If your source is Azure SQL and the ultimate destination is On-Prem SQL, you could use SSIS and skip the CSV all together.

If you want to stick to an Azure PAAS solution you could consider using Azure Data Factory. You can setup a gateway to access the on-prem SQL server directly or if you really want to stick to a CSC then look into using a Logic App.

Answer (score 0):

**Azure Data Factory** is surely option.

Simple solution would be `pyodbc` driver with little bit of python. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/python-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

You can also try `sqlcmd` and bit of `powershell` or `bash` on top.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017